# Email database architecture

Tags: database, email, database-design, redis, database-schema

I'm not sure if this is a good email database architecture.

I use redis Inbox, Archive, Sent lists for every user to store Conversation Ids(or thread ids). Each conversation ID points to a redis list of message ids. Every message id points to a PostgreSQL message table. Whenever a message is sent or archived or deleted I move around the IDs in the redis lists.

Things are a little messy only when doing search across messages, and when getting messages from a thread, because you have to always check if a message in a thread belongs to you, sometimes people reply in the same thread but for a different set of users.

Is this a good approach? Are there better ideas? How to improve this one?

Comment: Why the end point of this schema is a PostgreSQL table ?

Comment: I cannot argue why with confidence. I think if I store messages in Redis as well it will take too much memory. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end your arguments were correct :)

http://redis.io/topics/faq

> Redis is an in-memory but persistent on disk database, so it
>   represents a different trade off where very high write and read speed
>   is achieved with the limitation of **data sets that can't be larger
>   than memory**

So you can't keep everything in Redis. Also, you can't conveniently do a text search, so keeping the actual message data in PostgreSQL or another database, like Solr, is necessary.

Ponder what is the real use of making a Redis layer in your case. If you keep Redis, it could deal with IDs very efficiently, and you could keep subjects and email addresses in it, too.

Best thing to be done is to start a few use cases :)

- Displaying latest messages (ordered by timestamp **ts**)

  ```
  > sadd messages 1 2
  > hmset message:1 ts 1411783175 author_id 1 subject "An e-mail for starting things up"
  > hmset message:2 ts 1411783150 author_id 2 subject "An early e-mail from the startup one"
  > hmset author_id:1 name "Johnny" email "john@somewhere.com"
  > hmset author_id:2 name "Sarah" email "masterchief@sarah.com"
  > sort messages by message:*->ts get message:*->subject
  1) "An early e-mail from the startup one"
  2) "An e-mail for starting things up"
  ```

In this case, **ts** is the epoch time of each message

- Listing users in a thread (e.g. thread # **1**)

  ```
  > sadd thread:1:messages 1 2
  > sort thread:1:messages get message:*->author_id store thread:1:authors
  > sort thread:1:authors get author_id:*->name get author_id:*->email
  1) "Johnny"
  2) "john@somewhere.com"
  3) "Sarah"
  4) "masterchief@sarah.com"
  ```

Here **thread:1:messages** has message ids, we store the authors in a **thread:1:authors** key.

In my experience with Redis, you must choose a good client (for PHP undoubtedly is PHPRedis [ https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis ], since it's a C extension compiled to php module), and do a good amount of processing in your application too.

Hope that was useful.